# When can threads enter synchronised methods?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two question that are confusing me. I am not professional in java

**Q1. Two threads A and B hit two different synchronized methods in an object at the same time. Will they both continue?
Which of the following option gives the valid outcome for the above question?**

a.  Yes, because the methods are synchronized.

b.  No, only one method can acquire the lock.

c.  No, because the methods are synchronized.

d.  Yes, two different threads hit

**Q2. wait, notify and notifyAll methods are not called on Thread, they are called on Object . True or false?**

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you doubt is and this would lead to a more informed answer.  I suggest you read the Javadoc for Object, and it will explain the second answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1 is kind of vague:**  Most likely, it is asking about two different *instance methods* of the same class, both methods are declared to be `synchronized` *on the instance itself*, and the two threads are calling the methods on the *same instance*.  E.g.,

```
class Foobar {
    synchronized SomeType methodA(...) { ... }
    synchronized SomeOtherType methodB(...) { ... }
}
```

That's how *I* would interpret the question, but the way it's written, it leaves a lot of weasel room.

So anyway, suppose we have one instance, `foo`, and thread A tries to call `foo.methodA()` while thread B tries to call `foo.methodB()` "at the same time."

Here's what will happen:

Both calls will succeed, but they will be *serialized*.  That is to say, either the methodA() call will complete before the methodB() call begins, or vice versa.  The operating system will not allow the two calls to *overlap*.  Without more information, there is no way to tell which thread will get to go first.

Whichever thread gets to run first, the other thread will be *blocked* until the first thread completes its method call.  "Blocked" is just like waiting at a red light when you're driving somewhere.  You get to the red light, you stop until it turns green, and then you continue on your way.

We don't normally think or talk about threads being blocked while waiting for mutexes.  In a well-designed program, it isn't any more interesting than stopping at a red light on your way to work.  The only time it *does* become interesting, is when there's a huge horrible traffic jam at the light or, in the programming world, if the mutex is a *bottle neck* (i.e., it has too much *contention*).

**Question 2 is even worse** because `Thread` is a subclass of `Object`.  You *can* call `t.wait()` and `t.notify()` on some Thread, `t`, but it usually is not a smart idea because the library itself uses `t.wait()` and `t.notify()` for its own purposes, and the library use of those methods might interfere with your use or vice versa.

The best answer I can think of for the question is, "The `Object` class implements wait() and notify(), and when we call `foo.wait()` or `foo.notify()` we are almost always calling the implementation from the Object class because it doesn't make sense for any class to override those methods.

Comment: thank allot for explaining...

Answer (score 1):

B are C are both correct - only one thread can enter any synchronized method at once. This applies even if different synchronized methods are being called simultaneously.

Regarding part 2, `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` are instance methods of the `Object` class, so "true" is correct - they are called on the (lock) Object.

Comment: Here they said there are **two different synchronized function** in an object. Still only one thread will have access?

Comment: Yes - only one thread, even if not the same method. I have clarified the answer